# How do I display (i.e.) 3rd index (4th) image in an array starting from the left, when the first 3 images are filtered with if statement?

Tags: html, css, angular, image, typescript

So I'm using AngularJS (front-end) and .NET Core (back-end) for my personal web dev project (musical instrument retailer website). I have a model called "Guitar" and I have all the guitar data inside the Guitar table in the DB, and each of them has a main image. Inside the .ts file, I brought in an array of guitars which currently is storing 5 data(guitars). Index 0, 1, 2 are Martin guitars, and 3, 4 are Gibson guitars. I have separated Martin and Gibson guitar into separate components in Angular, so they each have its own page and URL. And I also have guitar-card component for styling of an image using bootstrap's card. Below is how I used angular's condition statement to filter Gibson guitars and display them only.

```
<div *ngIf="guitar.brand == 'Gibson'">
  <app-guitar-card [guitar]="guitar"></app-guitar-card>
</div>
```

it takes up the image space for index 0, 1, 2 and starts displaying the 3rd index image from the 4th position which is on the right. But I want those first 3 images to not take up space when it's not even displayed on the webpage.
[Click here to see the screenshot of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV5qQ.png)

This is the gibson-list.component.html

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let guitar of guitars" class="left col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div *ngIf="guitar.brand == 'Gibson'">
        <app-guitar-card [guitar]="guitar"></app-guitar-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is gibson-list.component.ts

```
export class GibsonListComponent implements OnInit {
  guitars: Guitar[];

  constructor(private guitarService: GuitarService, private alertify: AlertifyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadGuitars();
  }

  loadGuitars() {
    this.guitarService.getGuitars().subscribe((guitars: Guitar[]) => {
      this.guitars = guitars;
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }
}
```

I tried solving this issue using css, but couldn't figure it out. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because divs are added through *ngFor with empty content cause of *ngIf.
Try this one instead:

ts file

```
filter(guitars,brand){
  return guitars.filter(g=>g.brand===brand)
}
```

html file

```
<div *ngFor="let guitar of filter(guitars,'Gibson')" class="left col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
```

---